# Remove dir '$'\r

Tags: linux, shell

Following a script error, I find myself with a directory impossible to delete.
Can you help me ?

```
me@Nas:/volume3/photo/Upload$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  1 SynologyPhotos SynologyPhotos     210 May 23 17:51  .
drwxrwxrwx  1 root           root                98 Nov 23  2021  ..
drwxr-xr-x  1 root           root               156 Jun 30  2022  @eaDir
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 SynologyPhotos SynologyPhotos  221888 May 23 16:57 'iPhone (A classer)'
drwx------  1 root           root                 0 May 23 17:32 'iPhone (A classer)'$'\r'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me      users             7537 Jun 30  2022  upload_iphone_sync.jpg
```

Can't find ***rm -R command*** to match : `'iPhone (A classer)'$'\r'`

Regards.

Comment: `rm -rf -- dirname`. You can start and  `tab tab` to get it auto escaped. Or your permissions are wrong. What is the error when you try to delete?

Comment: The name is already formatted to be copied and pasted into a shell command. The `$'` is not part of the name, it's (ksh/bash/zsh) shell syntax generated by (some GNU versions of) `ls` to tell you how to refer to the file.

Comment: And btw, questions about using command-line tools belong on [unix.se], not here. Stack Overflow is _only_ for questions about writing software.

Comment: BTW, notice how the directory is owned by root? That means you need to be root to delete it. `sudo` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(Community Wiki -- disclaiming reputation points -- because answering an off-topic question)</sub>

```
sudo rm -rf 'iPhone (A classer)'$'\r'
```

(`sudo` necessary only if you aren't already running as root)

That's it. `ls` already escaped the name for you: The quotes and the `$` aren't part of the name; instead, they're shell instructions to treat the whitespace as literal, and to expect the directory name to end with a carriage return.

Note that this command needs to be run in an extended shell -- ksh, bash, zsh; it won't work with baseline POSIX sh, as `$''` is not part of the standard.